# Mysql finding count of previous date of occurences for each record

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table to store id, sid with a date time.
id is used as primary key and no meaning in data.
sid is used to identify entity.

eg.

```
id  sid     date 
--------------------
1   1    2020-01-12
2   2    2020-01-01
3   1    2019-12-31
4   2    2019-12-31
5   1    2019-12-31
6   1    2019-11-01
7   3    2019-11-01
8   3    2018-12-21
9   2    2018-12-21
```

Then I would like to query for each record, count occurrences in the same table with the previous date of current date, and with the same sid, like:

```
id  sid  date       previous_count
----------------------------------
1    1  2020-01-12      2
2    2  2020-01-01      1
3    1  2019-12-31      1
4    2  2019-12-31      1
5    1  2019-12-31      1
6    1  2019-11-01      0
7    3  2019-11-01      1
8    3  2018-12-21      0
9    2  2018-12-21      0
```

Explanation:
for row 1, since `sid 1` has two records in `2019-12-31`, which is the previous date of `2020-01-12` for `sid 1` in the table, it has 2 in `previous_count`;

while in row 2, since `sid 2` has only 1 record in `2019-12-31`, which is the previous date of `2020-01-01` for `sid 2`, it has 1 in `previous_count`.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your are looking for `dense_rank() - 1`:

```
select t.*,
       (dense_rank() over (partition by sid order by date) - 1) as previous_count
from t
order by id;
```

In older versions of MySQL, you could use variables or a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*,
       (select count(distinct t2.date)
        from t t2
        where t2.sid = t.sid and t2.date < t.date
       ) as previous_count
from t
order by id;
```

EDIT:

Ahh, I think I may have misunderstood the problem.  I think this does what you want:

```
select t.*, lag(cnt, 1, 0) over (partition by sid order by date)
from (select t.*,
             count(*) over (partition by sid, date) as cnt
      from t
     ) t
order by id;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7ea54dbb003e7945ea7ba607d937dcbe) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: I am using mysql 5.x so I am trying your old version code. but it seems not what I want as I need to count with the date just smaller than the row's date, not all dates smaller than the row's date

Comment: @kt_at_kt . . . I see you have duplicate `sid`/`date` pairs.  In that case, you want `dense_rank()` rather than `row_number()`.

Comment: Your edited ans is very close to my desired result, but seems still not what I want. you can see row 5 in your ans. My desired result should be 1, but you give 2